# Is it possible merge back to trunk changes on a branch before reintegration of that branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using SVN 1.6 and I want to create a branch, his branch will be eventually merged back to trunk but before that I will need every week merge some specific changes on the branch to trunk.

I can not find in SVN documentation anything against that, I have made also a small test to check is this procedure will work. But I'm still afraid this is against some SVN good practices I did not read about, so, the question is:

Can this cause some problem on the final reintegration?
This merges from branch to trunk will be considered like revisions that need to be merged again to branch before reintegration?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a "cherry-pick" merge from time to time from your branch to trunk, then the best thing to do when the branch eventually merges "all the way" is *not* to do a reintegration merge. Instead, just do another cherry-pick merge and select all the revisions you have not merged already.

In later versions of SVN (I think 1.8), merging has improved to where you ought to be able to just let SVN choose what revisions to merge for you based on what has already been merged, but I know this has caused some problems in older versions. Merging a specific set of revisions shouldn't ever cause any problems.

The [svn mergeinfo command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html) can tell you which versions still need merging when you go to do your final merge, or TortoiseSVN will "gray out" the revisions which have already been merged if you click "show log" in the merge dialog. I don't know when it was added, but actually "hide non-mergeable revisions" is a checkbox that can help for this purpose as well.